# How to transform missing values ​through a multiplication of a "K" factor starting at the last valid value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, interpolation, missing-data

My problem is to apply a multiplication factor `K=0.5` starting at the first valid number that appears before the missing values ​​"NaN" and keep applying that factor K to the calculated values ​​until the last missing value NaN of the period.

TABLE A:

```
Bird1  Bird2  Bird3 
    
     100  50      200  
     50   40      100  
     40   40      80  
     NaN  80      200  
     NaN  50      NaN 
     NaN  90      NaN 
     100  12      40
```

The result should be as per the table below. How to implement this code in python?

TABLE B:

```
Bird1   Bird2    Bird3 

 100     50      200  
 50      40      100  
 40      40      80  
 20      80      200  
 10      50      100 
 5       90      50 
 100     12      40
```

Using the `df.interpolate()` command is not suitable because it also uses the value after the missing values ​​NaN. I would just like a constant `K` starting and being applied to the first value BEFORE the missing values ​​NaN.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom interpolation function:

```
def interp(s, K=0.5):
    # group by non-NA then NA
    g = s.groupby(s.notna().cumsum())
    # get decreasing factors
    factor = K**g.cumcount()
    # interpolate
    return g.transform('first').mul(factor)

out = df.apply(interp)
#     df.apply(interp, K=0.5)
```

output:

```
   Bird1  Bird2  Bird3
0  100.0   50.0  200.0
1   50.0   40.0  100.0
2   40.0   40.0   80.0
3   20.0   80.0  200.0
4   10.0   50.0  100.0
5    5.0   90.0   50.0
6  100.0   12.0   40.0
```